# Calculate the small-signal voltage gain of the circuit

Tags: gain

The following is from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), Page 155.

Calculate the small-signal voltage gain of the circuit shown in Fig. 5.35.

[image]

Well, the book said the gain is \$A_v = g_{m1} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o2})\$

However, my calculation shows that

$$\frac{-V_{out}} {r_{o2}} = \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o1}} + V_{in} g_{m1}$$

$$\Rightarrow A_v = -g_{m1} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o2})$$

Comment: This is normal in electronic that we often skip the minus sign.  We usually omit this "minus" sign because we know what this "minus" sign represents/means. This "minus" only informs us that the output voltage is the 180-degree phase shift with respect to the input voltage. That's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculation is correct because the circuit reduces to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDo5dL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the output voltage is \$\mathrm{0-v_o=g_{m1} \ v_{in} (r_{o1} || r_{o2})}\$ therefore the voltage gain is

$$
\mathrm{A_v=\frac{v_o}{v_{in}}=-g_{m1} \ (r_{o1} || r_{o2})}
$$

But the book uses \$|A_v|\$ which eliminates the sign.